# What could cause my browserS to keep crashing?

Tags: windows-7, browser

The situation:  Windows 7 ultimate on standard box 4 GB RAM.
The problem: IE 8 kept on crashing.  Tried upgrading to IE 9 - no better.
Then I thought I will have to kick IE into touch and go with Firefox.  Same problem Firefox crashes.  Gave Chrome a chance - same problem the browser just says sorry, and closes / restarts.

Other problems, this is not the best machine I have ever had, Word sometime closes unexpectedly, and I have trouble with Microsoft Updates failing first time.

Comment: It just sounds like you have an unreliable machine. Have you tried letting memtest86+ run for a few hours to try to rule out a hardware problem? Have you checked fans?

Comment: Have you verified the system is clean of viruses or malware and run [System File Checker](http://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/system_file_checker.mspx?mfr=true)?

Comment: After you've confirmed that your system is malware-free, I'd go with what David said. Ideally you should test each stick of RAM separately.

Comment: It seems that system files are corrupted, thus all browsers could be affected by a problem with one key file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[I am unsure of the etiquette here]  I have a corrupted system, the browserS crashing was the result of a general problem.  Perhaps one clue was that it was not just one browser, but all 3 that I tried.

Other than using sfc / scannow as a troubleshooting technique, I cannot see how my question will help other readers.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue where browsers would eventually lock up and often lead to blue screen crash. Someone suggested that it might be an overheating problem. I removed the CPU fan and there was a layer of dust on the CPU. Sure enough, after cleaning it off all issues were resolved.